# How to create this curved 90-degree-angle quickly

Tags: edges, topology, bevel

I want to make this:

[image]

from this:

[image]

I created the beveled edge by beveling on the cube, then beveling the inner edge, however that resulted in a weird diamond shape:

[image]

So I ended up disolving edges and fighting with the uncooperative knife tool for the next 2 minutes or so, just to get a clean bevelled edge like I wanted. How to do it faster, without the hassle?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

### First method:

This one will work only for external **Edge Loop** and will give ugly ngon, so it's just for the pure knowledge. Better skip to second one.

Select corner vertex, press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>, move mouse to get desired angle, use scroll to get more vertices. You can tweak it as well in in **Tools Panel**.

[image: first]

### Second method:

This is with proper/clean/nice looking topology.

1. Make two **Loop Cuts** trough the surrounding faces - <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>.
2. Delete corner face.
3. Select both **Edges**.
4. <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> > **Bridge Edge Loops**.
5. Set values in **Tools Panel** or hit <kbd>F6</kbd>.

[image: second]

### Edit:

I don't know math so maybe someone could elaborate more about what makes smooth corner perfectly 90 degrees. Below some doodling over result by **Bridge Edge Loops** method.

[image: 90]

Comment: Could person who DV my answer could tell me what's wrong with both methods? It's quite strange to DV proper, extended answer :)

Comment: The question ask how to create 90 degree but according to your answer when bevel and cuts given that will not match the to points 90 degree look its manually 90 degree curve not perfect 90 degree. Thanks

Comment: @ateks Sorry, I can't understand you really well and I'm not that good at maths, but for me 90 degree is 90 degree no matter if it's done by hand or by property. Maybe someone could explain how perfect is this bridge loop method and in the mean time you can compare it to any other method if it's 90 degrees enough. Also check my edit, maybe you could explain it to us better.

Answer (score 7):

In general you want to change the curvature of the corner from the square face to something more rounded. One method to get there is to make corner vertices as if they were inset and bevel the result.

1. Start with the square face in the corner.

   [image: screenshot-1]
2. Select both vertices in the inner and in the outer parts of the corner. Use the *Connect Vertex Path* tool with <kbd>J</kbd> to create an edge between them splitting a face.

   [image: screenshot-2]
3. Select original edges of the square face which are forming the corner and dissolve them (<kbd>X</kbd> > *Dissolve Edges*).

   [image: screenshot-3]
4. Select created edge which is the only one left and bevel it as needed; make the offset not so high so the beveled edges don't get in touch with those of the connecting faces; no need to create  tris here.

   [image: screenshot-4]

Comment: This and "bridge edge loops" the only answers so far that will produce quads.

Answer (score 7):

You can also use the *Spin* tool (<kbd>⎇ Alt</kbd><kbd>R</kbd>):

1. Align the view with the axis around which you want to spin/bend.
2. Place the 3D cursor level with the edges you wish to start and stop the bend at (you can use snapping if you need to be really precise, but I rarely find myself needing to).
3. Press <kbd>⎇ Alt</kbd><kbd>R</kbd> and adjust the angle and segments as needed.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

I don't think the diamond shape is so weird, but you can do the following:

- Keep your beveled initial setting:

[image]

Then:

- Select the 'diamond' parts
- Subdivide using <kbd>W</kbd>
- Select the resulting vertices
- Scale except along the Z axis (if you are in top view): <kbd>S</kbd> then <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd> to deselect Z
- Adjust grabbing to the wanted location
- Remove doubles using <kbd>W</kbd>

[image]

Answer (score 4):

1. Delete the corner vertex.

[image]

2. Select the bottom vertex and press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> -> **Cursor to Selected**.

[image]

3. Select the corner vertex.

[image]

4. Selected vertex and go to **Tools Panel** -> **Add** -> **Spin**

[image]

5. Spin with -90 degrees and if you want to increase the vertex press <kbd>F6</kbd> to increase.

[image]

Select the curve vertex and Press F to fill the faces

Comment: This doesn't get the inner bevel, right? (Perhaps check the original post again?)

Answer (score 1):

Method 1: Get a flat square, select an edge, and use the bevel modifier (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> & scroll) to make it round. Extrude the shape to get depth.

Method 2: Compose a cylinder into the edge of a cube (providing the rounded edge) without 2 adjacent faces then merge both models & delete duplicate vertices.

Method 3: Select both outer edges that you want to join with a curved plane then select "Bridge edge loops" and change the smoothness to make a curve.

Comment: Two of your three methods are covered in my answer. I don't think that repeating each other bring any good to this site.

Comment: @Biarity plase add images to your answer, it will be easier to understand if you show the steps for each of the proposed solutions.