# How can I round a corner that is made up of two different objects?

Tags: bezier-curves, bevel

First of all I apologise if this is a silly question but I have been unable to work out how to do this in Blender and was wondering if anyone can help.

I am making a model of a train and would like to make the window frames rounded at the edges as they are in real life. I have been unable to work out how to do this with the Bevel function in Blender 2.77. Is there a simple way to make these windows with rounded edges instead of square ones?

[image: an example of one of the corners I want to make rounded]

[image: Second image showing the wider context of the model and how the windows are formed from separate shapes]
Any help would be gratefully received.

Thanks

Comment: Why don't you create a new frame inside of this window that has rounded edges? That way, with one piece, you can round all 4 corners at once.

Comment: Could you provide a Blend file so we can see some more context?

Comment: I had considered creating a new frame inside of the window but was unsure as to how I would create the curved edges required.

Comment: I am not sure how to upload a blend file. Let me see what I can do. 

PS - Thanks for your comments so far.

Comment: Use https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ to upload the blend file and add it to your post.

Comment: Stephen, there is a Youtube channel from a user in Germany, [Pascal Alt](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCoLJWXZtmBFAbgsl4pyLpoQ), who currently has in progress a series of tutorials on modeling a train. While the series presently is devoted to a steam locomotive, and not cars, he does address making corners of windows, among a host of other valuable techniques in using Blender. i would note that the series has a couple of glaring errors, at least to one who knows about trains, but is generally well worth watching. The windows he does are in tutorial number 14, or so.

Comment: Literally just asked a couple days ago. https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/78322/how-to-create-this-curved-90-degree-angle-quickly

Answer (score 0):

Usually in Blender, there are two ways one would round the corner of a window, the edges of which are made from more than one object. One is to make the window a separate object from both of the other two; the other is to combine the objects surrounding the window into a single object, perhaps while leaving the individual meshes separate.

Tools and techniques one would ordinarily use in rounding a corner do not work in Blender across multiple objects.

Answer (score 0):

The best option would be to make the whole window surround from one mesh. This would allow you to bevel each corner.

You can add extra geometry, create the [bevel](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/meshes/editing/subdividing/bevel.html) and remove the extra to get the result you are after.

[image: bevel and trim]