# Cutout of plane with rounded corners

Tags: bevel

I'm trying to cut a door out of plane, but I need the edges to be rounded. So sort of an inverted bevel. I'm a complete noob can't find the right way to do this. In the pic, the circle would be roughly the radius I need, but the interior of that rectangle would be removed.

[image]

Reference image: RV doorway

[image]

Comment: Related/duplicate maybe: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/78322/how-to-create-this-curved-90-degree-angle-quickly/78326#78326

Comment: some helpful ideas, but nothing immediately applied, at least not that I could figure out. That was beveling both inside and outside, I just need the inside cutout.

Comment: Do you want it to be quad based?

Comment: please add a reference image of what you are trying to get.

Comment: A lot easier way is to extrude faces which corners you want to bevel out of the surface and bevel corner edges of the extrusion. Then delete extrusion and you'll be left with only whole with beveled corners. Topology might be needed to be corrected, so no Ngons, no tris (preferably) if you plan to use Subsurf or stuff

Comment: @MrZak I think your suggestion was the fastest/simplest. I used that as the basis for my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I found the easiest way based on answers posted and Mr Zak's comment on the extrude. If you inset (press I), then extrude (press E), you can take the outer edges and bevel (ctrl-B), then delete all the extruded parts (use cursor select by pressing C to pick the faces quickly, then press x and select Faces). Takes about 20 seconds.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If i understood the question you need to curve the edges

Select the side verts and Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> to bevel

Select the edge and subdivide both edges

Select the face and press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> and select cursor to selected

Select the single vert and press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> selection to cursor

Repeat to other side also.

Select both the verts and Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> to bevel and with the scroll wheel increase the verts

Select the face and delete or extrude it.

[image]

Comment: Note that this will create Ngons.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that this can be done automatically.

Anyway you need 5 minutes:

Starting from one plane, select the two upper vertices, press CTRL+Shift+B, drag the mouse and use Scroll for more vertices. Now you just have to merge this plane in the rest of the model, select the vertices and press F to create the faces, it's important to get a pattern like the one on the image. Then delete the central face.

[image]